# contentResolver not returning distinct data from MediaProvider

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentresolver

I have this function, which is supposed to give the list of albums or buck_display_name(s) but it is returning repeated value. I have searched a lot but could not find any help:

```
String[] projection = {"Distinct "+MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,null,null,"bucket_display_name ASC");
    Log.i("ResultCount",String.valueOf(cursor.getCount()));

    int i=0;
    _ALBUM_IDs = new ArrayList<>();
    URIs = new ArrayList<>();
    _IDs = new ArrayList<>();
    _ALBUM_NAMES = new ArrayList<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        Log.i("Row",String.valueOf(i));
        for (int j=0;j<cursor.getColumnCount();j++){
            Log.i("Column "+j,cursor.getColumnNames()[j]+", value: "+cursor.getString(j));
        }
        _ALBUM_IDs.add(cursor.getString(0));
        _IDs.add(cursor.getString(1));
        URIs.add(cursor.getString(2));
        _ALBUM_NAMES.add(cursor.getString(3));
        i++;
    }
```

The output from the nested loop:

```
I/ResultCount: 6
I/Row: 0
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: -2075821635
I/Column 1: _id, value: 43
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSC_0339.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DCIM
I/Row: 1
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: -2075821635
I/Column 1: _id, value: 44
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSC_0934.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DCIM
I/Row: 2
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: -2075821635
I/Column 1: _id, value: 45
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSC_2057m.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DCIM
I/Row: 3
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: -2075821635
I/Column 1: _id, value: 46
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSC_2132.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DCIM
I/Row: 4
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: -2075821635
I/Column 1: _id, value: 47
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/DSC_4258.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DCIM
I/Row: 5
I/Column 0: bucket_id, value: 902704159
I/Column 1: _id, value: 63
I/Column 2: _data, value: /storage/emulated/0/DataSync/DSC_0249.jpg
I/Column 3: bucket_display_name, value: DataSync
```

You can see there are repeated values of bucket_id , bucket_display_name. Why is this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `_id` values are distinct, so the function works correctly.

The `ContentResolver.query()` method does not really allow you to filter for distinct values in a specific column (this would require GROUP BY, which is not possible either), unless the content provider actually gives you a data source for that.
You have to filter the results manually.

Comment: the `_id` are obviously distinct because here this column is probably some sort of PRIMARY KEY. Anyway thanks for your reply, can you give any idea about GROUP BY

Comment: actually I did filter the result manually by using hashsets but I wanted to fetch less result from database because it would be better in terms of performance.